# Recursive function, which writes integer digits in an array(vector) in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, counting, digits

I have a C++ program, in which I have to create a recursive function that writes all the digits of a given positive integer in an array  - in this case a vector.
However, when I compile the program and enter a number, it stops working. I want to ask why  this happens?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    vector <int> arr;
    int temp;
    int fill_Array(int num)
    {
        if(num>=1 && num<=9)
        {
            arr.push_back(num);
        }

        temp = fill_Array(num)%10;
        arr.push_back(temp);
        num/=10;

    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        fill_Array(n);
        for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This will be infinite recursion. Also your function is not returning anything.

Comment: *Debugger* and single step this. The problem(s) will be *obvious*.

Comment: There must be least one path through a recursive function that doesn't  recurse, and the recursive paths should not recurse with the same argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given code, recursion function does not returning any value, so return type for that function have no use.
calling the function for recursion is in the wrong place. Correct code given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <int> arr;
int temp;
void fill_Array(int num)
{
    if(num>=1 && num<=9)
    {
        arr.push_back(num);
    }
    else{
        temp = num%10;
        arr.push_back(temp);
        fill_Array(num/=10);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    fill_Array(n);
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of reasons I can see:

1. There is no conditional to stop the recusion so it will keep going until it runs out of stack or memory. I presume you want to stop when num is zero
2. fill_Array has no return value so will assign temp with some random value which will be pushed into the array

Also why use recursion for this when iterative would be easier and more obvious what it is doing